# Azure DevOps (VSTS) - Jenkins Pipeline - Set user agent

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Azure DevOps (formerly known as VSTS) to start a new Jenkins build when changes are pushed.

Is there a way to define a user agent for all HTTP requests that are made from the Azure Agent to the Jenkins Server? At the moment there is no user agent set at all.

Comment: Why you want to define a  user agent in Azure devops?

Comment: HI! For multiple reasons. First of all to be able to analyze the Webserver Logs properly and differentiate between the ones that come from Azure and the ones that do not. The other reason are safety reasons, for example, we would like to set some access rules, based on the User Agent. Thanks!

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I would appreciate a response. Thank you!

Comment: Hi,TheNiceGuy,I am not familiar with user agent,can you explain more information about user Agent?Thanks.

Comment: I mean the user agent that is for example send when visiting a website through a browser (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent). Currently the HTTP requests that are performed by the Azure Pipeline do not include a user agent. I believe that they should at least send a general user agent, that seems to be the industry. Additionaly, I believe that it would be very beneficial if you could define a custom one so that you can identify the request. At the moment I don't see any way that would allow me to check if the incoming request is authorized, before letting it reach my application. Thanks

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT (this is just to reference you)

Comment: We are exploring this issue and will respond to you as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you! 

PS: I forgot a word in my long comment, of course it should be "industry standard", not just "industry"

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT Hi there, it has been over a month and I have not received a reply regarding this issue..